# shared project and database

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have a visual studio project and I want to use it on another computer. I found that there is a way to upload the project but I wanted to know if its possible to share also my database so it will be linked to the project anytime I change the computer Im working with, and the database will update itself on both computers.

?

Comment: Yes, there's lots of ways.

Comment: like what for example?

Comment: Think through the problem. You can write scripts that you apply to the database to bring it up to date. These are called migrations. You check these scripts into source control and apply them to bring databases up to date.

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks!

Comment: You can store the database on a cloud based environment so you can access it from any machine an example of this would be Azure. You can upload the project to a source control management system such as GIT. Or you can script out your database schema and data if needed, this way you can run this script at any point to create your database schema and seed any required data, you can store this script in your project that is hosted online.

Comment: And I won't need to change the database path on the code right? It will be fully identical in all computers?

Comment: It depends what you mean by the path. As you have not shown any examples of code, if you are referring to the connection string for the database on that instance. Then yes this can stay the same as it will be hosted elsewhere, meaning it will always be available to be accessed.

Comment: That's what I meant thanks

Answer (score 0):

create a database project along with your c# project and put all your tables, stored procs, etc. in it. check in the database project in your version control. when moving to a new computer "publish" the database project the first time, or do a "sql compare" any consecutive time to apply the db changes.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272677(v=vs.103).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272690(v=vs.103).aspx